# Remove Storeitem without sending a delete request to server in ExtJS4

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1

I want to remove a Storeitem in ExtJS4.1 using `store.remove(item)`, but i don't want to send a delete request to the server.

In the stores proxy api i have only the read-Url defined:

`api: { 
      read:     '/daten/zhalter'
    }`

Now when i remove the item a javascript error is thrown. I found out that it comes because i don't have destroy-url defined, when i define one everything is fine.

My Question is: How can i  delete an item without sending a delete request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found an answer by myself. I turned `autosync` off for that command:

```
quellStore.autoSync = false;    
quellStore.remove(item);    
quellStore.autoSync = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add destroy property:

> api: {destory: 'url/delete'}

Then use:

> store.sync();